# Wordpress permalink hook for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, hook

I have permalink hooks for pages, and want write same function for custom post type,  I try change `page_link` to `custom_post_type`, but it not work

```
add_filter('page_link', 'rating_permalinkas', 10, 3);
add_filter('page_type_link', 'rating_permalinkas', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
add_filter('post_link', 'rating_permalinkas', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'rating_permalinkas', 10, 3);
```